# Find $\lim_{n \to \infty}n\int_{0}^{1}(f(t))^n \, dt$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, analysis

> Find the limit $$\lim_{n \to \infty}n\int_{0}^{1}(f(t))^n \, dt$$ where $f:[0,1] \to \mathbb{R}$ is a non negative function such that $f(t) < 1$, $\forall t \in [0,1]$

*My attempt:*

We know that $f([0,1])$ is bounded so let $C$ be an upper bound of the function $f$. Then

$$n\int_{0}^{1}(f(t))^n \,dt < n\int_{0}^{1}C^n\,dt.$$

I can't conclude after this.

Comment: Apply the Squeeze theorem

Comment: Is f continuous?

Comment: No it is not mentioned

Comment: Then the behavior of the limit depends on the properties of $f$, especially when $\sup f=1$.

Comment: The integral may not exist . Some additional hypothesis on $f$ is necessary.

Comment: You can apply dominated convergence theorem (The function is always Lebesgue integrable if it is Lebesgue measurable).

Comment: As a simple counterexample if $f$ is not assumed continuous, if you let $f(x) = x$ except that $f(1) = 0$, then $n \int_0^1 (f(t))^n\,dt = \frac{n}{n+1} \to 1$ as $n \to \infty$.

Comment: There is no such constant $C$ unless  additional  assumptions on $f$ are made (continuity, for example)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you assume $f$ to be continuous we know by compactness of $[0,1]$ that $C < 1$. Follwoing your observation we define a sequence
$$ n\int_{0}^{1}(f(t))^n \,dt \leq n C^n =: a_n. $$
As each $a_n$ is a positive real number we may conisder the quotient
$$ \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n} = \frac{n+1}{n} C $$
which converges to $C$. The Ratio Test tells us now that $a_n$ converges to zero and so the original sequence.

More about the ratio test can be found [here](http://mathonline.wikidot.com/the-ratio-test-for-sequence-convergence).